# EditText View is absurd after adjustPane

Tags: android, android-edittext, adjustpan

I have an EditText at the bottom of the screen. I want to use "adjustPane" for when the keyboard opens.
The problem is that the screen is panning just enough for the first line of text to be visible, but not enough to see beneath it. The EditText "box" has about 3 lines height and it gets cut. 
Is there a way to make the screen pane enough so the whole EditText will be shown?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you put up some example source code and UI layouts?

Comment: There is nothing to put...  There i a simple EditText. nothing special...

Comment: There's nothing you can really do about it - this is how `adjustPane` works.  The only work around I can think of is is to add another empty view below the EditText and make it visible when the keyboard is shown and hide when the keyboard is hidden.  However catching the keyboard shown/hidden events is very difficult in android.